# How to provide different sets of data to different users in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a newbie to the django framework and trying to make a watchlist for stocks. I've already made the crux of the webapp, where-in, a user can search for a quote and add it to their watchlist, along with relevant data about that quote.

**What I want to do now is**, to save the separate watchlists that different users are creating (after creating an account on my site) and upon logging in to my site, they can view their personalized watchlist and edit it.
I'm using a model for storing the data for the watchlist quotes and looking for a way to provide the different personalized watchlists depending upon the logged in user.

Can anyone give me a lead on how to employ the logic for this? Do I need to use two data bases - one for the data of the users and the other one for storing the respective user watchlists? If yes, how do I connect everything?

**EDIT:** Ever used a stock investment app? The way every user/customer can log in to their account and make/edit and save their watchlists in the app - that is the functionality I want to implement. How/Where do I store so many watchlists?

Answer (score 1):

use 'request.user' from your view, to know the user who sent the request and return the corresponding watchlist

Comment: request.user will give me the user from the admin panel, that is, it will give me the name of the admin currently logged in. However I do not want that. I want to save the watchlists for the external users/people just visiting and using my website. Ever used a stock investment app? The way every user can log in to their account and make/edit their watchlists in the app - that is what I want to achieve.